# Remove newsfeed 512 character limitation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, newsfeed

Is there any way to remove 512 character limitation of a newsfeed in Sharepoint Server 2013?

Answer (score 0):

[There is no out of the box setting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/243ca254-2ec9-4954-8bf8-3b0c55bdda4c/customize-post-length-in-news-feed-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization) where you can extend the 512 char limit. However there are a few workarounds to accomplish this, but I'm not sure that's what you want. Maybe a blog feature would suit your needs better? Or if you're using Yammer, which is a tool much better suited for greater lenght posts.

Reference:

- [Overview of microblog features, feeds, and the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Integrate Yammer with on-premises SharePoint 2013 environments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270535.aspx)